# Report specific metric periodically

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have a specific metric that I want to report periodically, I know how to do it once by using

```
GaugeService.submit("myQueue", queue.size())
```

My question is how do I configure my application to call this periodically(every 1 second for instance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html), and schedule a task to be run at your requested interval:

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = ....;
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> GaugeService.submit("myQueue", queue.size()), 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: I thought about using @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000) but wanted to check if there is something for this in spring-boot out of the box, I'll use this suggestion if there is no other way.